# Changing user in a script?

Tags: users, init-script, su, upstart

I am trying to change user in order to execute a specific command during startup. It fails silently and apparently the userchange isn't carried out as I can tell that the command isn't executed.

What am I doing wrong in my below shown initscript?

```
respawn
console none

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
  su -u anotheruser -c "myCommand" >> "myLogfile.log"
end script
```

Comment: [You could also use `cron`, i.e. a `crontab` `@reboot` entry, I suppose.](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/372) (Output will be sent via mail.)

Comment: The best answer is [on SuperUser - pass a HEREDOC to `sudo -u someuser bash`](http://superuser.com/a/468163/33589)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are running recent version of ubuntu or a distribution based on [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/). You can check `/var/log/daemon.log` for errors.

The standard `su` takes the syntax `su [options] [username]`. Checkout `man 1 su`. You might want to try :

```
su -c "myCommand" anotheruser >> "myLogfile.log"
```

Also, a couple of things would happen (mostly not desirable)

1. `myLogfile.log` would be owned by `root`.
2. `myLogfile.log` would be created on `/` (root directory) if you don't use an absolute path like `/tmp/myLogfile.log` (because upstart runs with pwd set to `/`).

If you want the file to be owned by `anotheruser` you might switch the command to.

```
su -c "myCommand >> /tmp/myLogfile.log" anotheruser
```

This might cause problems if you have leftover `myLogfile.log` owned by `root` from earlier runs or if have not changed `myLogfile.log` to something like `/tmp/myLogfile.log` (normally, regular users can't create files on root dir `/`).

Comment: The ownership or permissions of myLogfile.log might be the issue. Be aware that root might have a stricter umask, and the permissions of myLogfile.log would then disallow writes.

Comment: How to provide the password for another user while changing the user in script?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've mixed up the syntax of `su` and `sudo`.

```
su -c 'mycommand' anotheruser
sudo -u anotheruser 'mycommand'
```